an automorphism $\tau$ of order two on a finite field and the map $a\mapsto aa^\tau$.
Let $F$ be a field and $\tau$ be an automorphism of $F$ of order two. Let $F_0$ be a subset of $F$ such that $a\in F_0$ if and only if $a^\tau=a$. Define the map $N:F^{\star}\rightarrow F_0^{\star}$ with the rule $a\mapsto a a^\tau$, where $a^\tau=\tau(a)$. It is easy to see that $N$ is a multiplicative homomorphism. But, it is asked that if $F$ is a finite field then $N$ is surjective. I can prove it when $|F|=q$ is even. In this case, if $b\in F_0^{\star}$ then $b^q=b$ and $N(b^{q/2})=b^{q/2}(b^{q/2})^\tau=b^{q/2}b^{q/2}=b^q=b$. I would like to know is there a proof when $q$ is odd?

You can do it using the fact that the multiplicative group is cyclic.
